# S3 GetBucketAccelerateConfiguration operation: Access Denied

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I need to grant user access to get AccelerateConfiguration for one bucket.
I set next permissions:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetAccelerateConfiguration",
            "s3:GetBucket*"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::some-bucket/*"
    }
]
}
```

And try this code:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3.get_bucket_accelerate_configuration(
  Bucket='some-bucket'
)
print(response)
```

But get an error like this:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetBucketAccelerateConfiguration operation: Access Denied
```

What Actions need to set to get access?

Comment: Bumping this. Did you ever get an answer?